# C++ how to pass object data into user defined conversion operator

Tags: c++, type-conversion, user-defined

I am doing some workshop for C++ and I am at loss on cast operator conversion. I am trying to display an double value by using object's data.

```
class object {
    int x;
    int y;
  public:
    operator double();
}
```

the workshop is to take the result of x / y and display it as double.
so if I were to display it by line like

```
std::cout << (double)A
```

assuming x is 3 and y is 2 the value should display as 1.5.
I am not sure how to make the definition of this, what I have is something like this

```
Object::operator double() {
    double dbl = 0;
    dbl = this->x / this->y
    return dbl;
}
```

Now this is obviously wrong because my x and y values are random and not obtaining the values of the object A. I am not sure how to pass the data into the function. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see why you think you need to pass data into the function; the function already has access to the members of the `object` instance it's operating on. (and, incidentally, you don't have to do `this->x` to reference it; you just need `x`)

Comment: (p.s. you want floating point division not integer division, so you have to convert to `double` before you divide, not after)

Comment: Just cast one of the values to a double in the division. This strikes me as a remarkably crappy exercise, so you may want to learn C++ from some other source, preferably a good textbook.

Comment: You should not be using a conversion type here.  The conversion to double is ambiguous (looking at the code) since there are many operations you can perform with `x` and `y` that would result in a `double`.  Use a more descriptive function, e.g. `ratio`.

Comment: @Thomas: The problem is too generic to really say such a thing confidently; e.g. if this were a class representing a rational number, then the given conversion to `double` would be a very natural thing.

Comment: `my x and y values are random and not obtaining the values of the object A` We probably need to see your actual program to figure out why you are getting *random* values. Perhaps something is not initialized.

Comment: Please copy and paste real code - your `operator double` as posted won't compile

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful answer if you follow the guidelines in [ask] and post a [mcve].  Right now we can't see how you are declaring, initialising or changing the variable A before you call the double operator.  I suspect your `x` and `y` values are random because of the way you create/initialise `A` not because of problems in your `operator double ()` but I can only guess because we can't see all of your code.

Comment: @TankorSmash `operator double ()` is a [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to the type `double`.

Answer (score 0):

> the workshop is to take the result of `x / y` and display it as `double`. so if I were to display it by line like
>
> ```
> std::cout << (double)A
> ```
>
> assuming `x` is 3 and `y` is 2 the value should display as `1.5`.

For that particular example, you should define a custom `operator<<`, eg:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const object &value)
{
    out << (double) value;
    return out;
}
```

Then you can pass the `object` directly to `cout` (or any other `ostream` descendant):

```
std::cout << A;
```

> I am not sure how to make the definition of this, what I have is something like this
>
> ```
> Object::operator double() {
>     double dbl = 0;
>     dbl = this->x / this->y
>     return dbl;
> }
> ```

What you have is fine, as far as declaring a conversion operator.  Though you should declare it as `const`, at least, since it does not modify any members of `object`.  Just be sure to watch out for `y=0`, since divide by 0 is an error.  And note that you are performing integer division instead of floating-point division, so you need to cast one of the values to `double` before dividing.

> Now this is obviously wrong because my `x` and `y` values are random and not obtaining the values of the object `A`.

If you are getting random results, it means your input is random to begin with (ie, you are likely not initializing your `x` and `y` variables).  In the `object` declaration you have shown, `x` and `y` are private, and you don't provide any constructor or setter method(s) to set their values.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class object {
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    object();
    object(int aX, int aY);

    int getX() const;
    void setX(int value);

    int getY() const;
    void setY(int value);

    operator double() const;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const object &value);
```

```
#include <limits>

object::object()
    : x(0), y(0)
{
}

object::object(int aX, int aY)
    : x(aX), y(aY)
{
}

int object::getX() const
{
    return x;
}

void object::setX(int value)
{
    x = value;
}

int object::getY() const
{
    return y;
}

void object::setY(int value)
{
    y = value;
}

object::operator double() const
{
    if (y != 0)
        return (double)x / (double)y;
    return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const object &value)
{
    out << (double) value;
    return out;
}
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
object A(3, 2);
std::cout << A;
```

```
object A;
A.setX(3);
A.setY(2);
std::cout << A;
```

Comment: A custom `operator <<` makes things too complicated.  The `operator double()` will convert an instance of the `A` class into a `double` and `std::basic_ostream` supports a [suitable `operator <<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) to take a `double` parameter.